# Using maintenance.css to maintenance-page.tpl.php

Tags: theming, maintenance-mode

I followed the link below so I can customize Maintenance Mode.

https://drupal.org/node/195435

How can I customize Maintenance Mode css? I tried to link the style sheet: maintenance.css to `maintenance-page.tpl.php` but I am getting nothing(no error)
Used this site for reference:https://drupal.org/node/1171800

Here is my code for `maintenance-page.tpl.php` I am using to link stylesheet:

```
<?php
/**
 * @file
 * Returns the HTML for a single Drupal page.
 *
 * Complete documentation for this file is available online.
 * @see https://drupal.org/node/1728148
 */
?>
<head> <link rel="stylesheet" href="/sites/all/themes/RAW_Gallery/css/maintenance.css" /> test</head>
<div id="page">

  <header class="header" id="header" role="banner">

    <?php if ($logo): ?>
      <a href="<?php print $front_page; ?>" title="<?php print t('Home'); ?>" rel="home" class="header__logo" id="logo"><img src="<?php print $logo; ?>" alt="<?php print t('Home'); ?>" class="header__logo-image" /></a>
    <?php endif; ?>

    <?php if ($site_name || $site_slogan): ?>
      <div class="header__name-and-slogan" id="name-and-slogan">
        <?php if ($site_name): ?>
          <h1 class="header__site-name" id="site-name">
            <a href="<?php print $front_page; ?>" title="<?php print t('Home'); ?>" class="header__site-link" rel="home"><span><?php print $site_name; ?></span></a>
          </h1>
        <?php endif; ?>

        <?php if ($site_slogan): ?>
          <div class="header__site-slogan" id="site-slogan"><?php print $site_slogan; ?></div>
        <?php endif; ?>
      </div>
    <?php endif; ?>

    <?php if ($secondary_menu): ?>
      <nav class="header__secondary-menu" id="secondary-menu" role="navigation">
        <?php print theme('links__system_secondary_menu', array(
          'links' => $secondary_menu,
          'attributes' => array(
            'class' => array('links', 'inline', 'clearfix'),
          ),
          'heading' => array(
            'text' => $secondary_menu_heading,
            'level' => 'h2',
            'class' => array('element-invisible'),
          ),
        )); ?>
      </nav>
    <?php endif; ?>

    <?php print render($page['header']); ?>

  </header>

  <div id="main">

    <div id="content" class="column" role="main">
      <?php print render($page['highlighted']); ?>
      <?php print $breadcrumb; ?>
      <a id="main-content"></a>
      <?php print render($title_prefix); ?>
      <?php if ($title): ?>
        <h1 class="page__title title" id="page-title"><?php print $title; ?></h1>
      <?php endif; ?>
      <?php print render($title_suffix); ?>
      <?php print $messages; ?>
      <?php print render($tabs); ?>
      <?php print render($page['help']); ?>

      <?php print render($page['content']); ?>
      <?php print $feed_icons; ?>
    </div>

    <div id="navigation">

      <?php if ($main_menu): ?>
        <nav id="main-menu" role="navigation" tabindex="-1">
          <?php
          // This code snippet is hard to modify. We recommend turning off the
          // "Main menu" on your sub-theme's settings form, deleting this PHP
          // code block, and, instead, using the "Menu block" module.
          // @see https://drupal.org/project/menu_block
          print theme('links__system_main_menu', array(
            'links' => $main_menu,
            'attributes' => array(
              'class' => array('links', 'inline', 'clearfix'),
            ),
            'heading' => array(
              'text' => t('Main menu'),
              'level' => 'h2',
              'class' => array('element-invisible'),
            ),
          )); ?>
        </nav>
      <?php endif; ?>

      <?php print render($page['navigation']); ?>

    </div>

    <?php
      // Render the sidebars to see if there's anything in them.
      $sidebar_first  = render($page['sidebar_first']);
      $sidebar_second = render($page['sidebar_second']);
    ?>

    <?php if ($sidebar_first || $sidebar_second): ?>
      <aside class="sidebars">
        <?php print $sidebar_first; ?>
        <?php print $sidebar_second; ?>
      </aside>
    <?php endif; ?>

  </div>

  <?php print render($page['footer']); ?>

</div>

<?php print render($page['bottom']); ?>
```

I know the custom Maintenance Mode is correct because I type "hello" between  in `maintenance-page.tpl.php`, login to my drupal theme and not see "hello."

So why can't I see maintenance.css ?

Comment: Well you should start by properly formatting your header with `<html><head></head><body>` ...

Comment: Should that matter? seeing that <div id=page> is not properly formatted. That worked.

Answer (score 1):

I created a maintenance-page.tpl.php and copied in your html from above.

I changed the href in the `<link>` tag to my main theme css, so from /sites/all/themes/RAW_Gallery/css/maintenance.css to /sites/all/themes/THEME/css/common.css. I then cleared the cache and everything worked.

Could it be the path to your CSS file is wrong? Or, perhaps it was not uploaded to the server, or perhaps you didn't clear the cache?

Comment: last but not least file permission :)

Answer (score 0):

Add the CSS file using [drupal_add_css()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!common.inc/function/drupal_add_css/7) as below:

```
<?php drupal_add_css(drupal_get_path('theme', 'RAW_Gallery') . '/css/maintenance.css'); ?>
```